# Accessing API of a kubernetes cluster from a different computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Lets say I have two computers; A and B. I created a kubernetes cluster using kops on AWS from computer A. How do I access the API of that cluster (like I do `kubectl get nodes`, it gives me the nodes of that cluster) using computer B?

Comment: Did you create a k8s config file with an a context for computer A? Then you can use it with `kubectl config use-context  computerA`. Maybe this helps:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

Comment: I did not manually create the k8s config file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure `kubectl` by defining a configuration file.

Since you are using `kops` you can use the instructions they're giving you here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/kubectl.md

```
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://<somes3bucket>
NAME=<kubernetes.mydomain.com>
/path/to/kops export kubecfg ${NAME}
```

You need to run the above instructions on `computer B` and it has to be correctly configured to have access to the `<somes3bucket>` bucket.

What the command will do is create a configuration file that holds the URL of your `apiserver` and the authentication certificates. If you are on a unix-like environment, that file will be created in `$HOME/.kube/config`.

Comment: `${GOPATH}/bin/kops export kubecfg ${NAME}` 
is giving me an error; `-bash: /bin/kops: No such file or directory`

Comment: it is installed, but `${GOPATH}` is not set.

Comment: Ok no need to use the ${GOPATH} variable, just use kops' full path instead of `${GOPATH}/bin/kops` (I'll correct the answer)

Comment: thank you. I am still getting this error though: `error fetching CA keypair: error in 'FindCert' attempting to load cert "ca": error loading certificate "s3://harith-kops/kops.yummyrecipes.ml/pki/issued/ca/keyset.yaml": could not parse certificate`

Comment: This is an error in your connection with aws s3. Check you have done what's required here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md (Setup your environment -> AWS section)